# Java.util.Date says time Zone unaware working fine with different time Zones

Tags: java, date, timezone

Beg your Pardon, I have updated the question a little to elaborate more.

I have an angular client which configured to run UTC + 3 (Istanbul)
which called to my server which running in UTC + 5 (Asia/Karachi)

I have been using Spring boot with SpringJPA with the below configurations

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone=true
spring.jackson.time-zone=Asia/Karachi
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

And my DB(MySql) running in UTC
The result for Date is working Perfect even though LocalDateTime was not able to cater to the timezone difference. (I do not doubt with LocalDateTIme but with Java.Util.Date)

[image]

Also, I have nothing special annotated for the Date property in the Entity

[image]

Once rest API invoke logging the date

```
 date           Sun Sep 05 18:00:00 PKT 2021
```

DataType     `` `date` DATETIME NULL ``  has been used for DB

Then the result in DB is below and it's in UTC

[image]

I have the same result for OffsetDateTime and ZonedDateTime but that is obvious since both carrying offset with it. But I need an explanation for the Date.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not a contradiction: an instance of `java.util.Date` doesn't *carry* any timezone information, but that doesn't mean it doesn't *use* the JVM default timezone.

Comment: Andy Turner’s Comment refers to the fact that the `java.until.Date` class’ `toString` method applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating a string. Quite misleading. One of many reasons to never use that class. Use only the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String toString() {
        // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
        BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
        int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
        if (index == BaseCalendar.SUNDAY) {
            index = 8;
        }
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');                        // EEE
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
        TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
        if (zi != null) {
            sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), TimeZone.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
        } else {
            sb.append("GMT");
        }
        sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

The above is the source of `Date.toString`. As you can see, a calendar utility is employed and via that, timezone info is used for display purposes. It's not inherent as such to `Date` itself, which is conceptually just and number which represents an offset from the epoch.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Both JPA (now Jakarta Persistence) and  Jackson support *java.time*.

Comment: @BasilBourque, I totally agree with you, but still, there are many people/applications using the Date class. Also, this is not something applied in real life but just an experiment.